# NetBeans cannot perform IO operation

Tags: java, netbeans, io

The NetBeans IDE keeps putting the error, saying that it cannot find the symbol IO. Cannot do any input or output operations with IO is since "IO" is considered as a symbol. Cannot find out why this is so.

Here is the very simple program i tried to run :-

```
public class CourseGrade
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        int examWeight = 70;    // Percentage weight given to examination
        int labWeight = 20;     // Percentage weight given to lab work
        int hwWeight = 10;      // Percentage weight given to homework 
                                                              assignment
        double examScore;       // Examination score obtained by student
        double labScore;        // Lab score obtained by student
        double hwScore;         // Homework score obtained by student
        double finalGrade;      // Final grade obtained by student

        // Ask student to input scores for exam, lab and nomework
        IO.output("Enter your exam grade: ");
        examScore = IO.inputDouble( );
        IO.output("Enter your lab grade: ");
        labScore = IO.inputDouble( );
        IO.output("Enter your homework grade: ");
        hwScore = IO.inputDouble( );

        // Computer final grade as the weighted sum of exam, lab and 
                                                     homework scores
        examScore = examScore * (examWeight / 100.0);
        labScore = labScore * (labWeight / 100.0);
        hwScore = hwScore * (hwWeight / 100.0);
        finalGrade = examScore + labScore + hwScore;

        // Output the final grade
        IO.outputln("Your final grade is " + finalGrade);  

    }
}
```

This is the Error that i got:-

error: cannot find symbol

IO.output("Enter the exam score :- \n");

symbol:   variable IO

location: class CourseGrade

I got this output for each of the IO that i used.
What is causing this ?

Comment: Are you missing an import statement for your `IO` class?

Comment: @JonK  I Didn't get you.

Comment: The way you are using `IO` suggests that it's a class, and that you're calling static methods declared by that class. If that's the case, make sure you're not missing an `import your.package.name.IO;` statement at the top of your .java file

Comment: @JonK It seems that the IO class included in the package, java.io. But even after i imported that class, the error persists.

Comment: `java.io` is just a package name, not a class. There is no `IO` class in the `java.io` package, so if that class name is correct it is very likely that its one of your own classes.

Comment: @JonK, What do you mean by "it's one of your own classes" ?

Comment: A class that you have written yourself (or perhaps your teacher wrote it?), one that isn't part of the standard set of Java classes.

Comment: @JonK Nope it isn't a class that i wrote.

Comment: Well it's not a standard Java class that you're using then. The only class called `IO` in the standard Java API is `com.sun.xml.internal.ws.policy.privateutil.PolicyUtils.IO`, and I'm certain it's not the one you're using.

Comment: @JonK so you would suggest that is use the class "System" for doing input and output operations ?

Comment: You could use `System` but not with those method signatures, you'll have to rewrite those bits of your code.

Comment: @JonK That sounds good, Thank you.